# Swift constant defined with LET sometimes produces EXC_BAD_ACCESS (EXC_I386_GPFLT) on read (OSX)

Tags: macos, swift, crash, exc-bad-access

In my AppDelegate I have a constant for a statusbar icon, used when the application is busy:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

let busyImage = NSImage(named: "BusyStatus");
...
```

In another class I'm accessing this several times over the time the app is running. On a Macbook Air with SSD I sometimes get an

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000103876cf9 swift_unknownRetain + 41
1   de.test.myapp   0x000000010304743b TestApp.AppDelegate.busyImage.getter : ObjectiveC.NSImage? (in TestApp) (AppDelegate.swift:0)
2   de.test.myapp   0x0000000102f9aa77 TestApp.Sync.(update (TestApp.Sync) -> () -> ()).(closure #2) (in TestApp) (Sync.swift:271)
```

The code there:

```
statusBarItem!.image = appDelegate!.busyImage
```

It's in a block called in the Main Thread:

```
let updateBlock: () -> () = {

    appDelegate!.statusBarItem!.image = self.appDelegate!.busyImage
        [... other code ...]
 }

 if NSThread.isMainThread()
 {
     updateBlock()
 }
 else
 {
     dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(),updateBlock)
 }
```

What can cause this and how to avoid this?

Comment: Before you do anything else you should test if your unwrapped optionals (those with a !) really exist before you assing them or assing to them.

Comment: Yes, I know. And they are testes a few lines above. You wonÄt enter this block if appDelegate oder statusBarItem is nil. - It seems to me that the getter from the NSImage class get's nil where it should not get any.

Comment: It seems, I got rid of this error simply be implementing a method in the AppDelegate setting the property, called from my block above... I keep the Question open, maybe someone can answer WHY this did not work.

Comment: So the problem seems to be that the block sets the property in the AppDelegate? And when the block calls a method in the AppDelegate to set the property it works?

Comment: In general both works, but setting the property directly sometimes got this error. Calling the method did not... yet.

Comment: Sounds like a threading problem, something like the block wanting to write the value while it is read from another thread.. ?!

Comment: Who is reading this? I'm setting the statusbar icon to a value from a let-constant and I'm never reading the value. And I always use mainthread to set it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be gone since swift 2.
Never had this issue again and changed absolutely nothing in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello People from the Internet,

My env is macOS 10.15.4 and I am running XCode 11.5 (11E608c) with Swift 5.

I have exactly the same issue with a little piece of code here which fails 100% of the time when using the rotation:

```
override func rotate(delta: float2) {
    let sensitivity: Float = 0.005
    rotation.y += delta.x * sensitivity    // FAILS with Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
    _viewMatrix = updateViewMatrix()
}
```

This code does not look weird at all. `rotation` is a vector of floats defined in the Class as:

```
var rotation: float3 = [0, 0, 0]
```

Now, I spent some time trying many versions of the same function and if I rewrite it as:

```
override func rotate(delta: float2) {
    let sensitivity: Float = 0.005
    var deltaX: Float = delta.x * sensitivity
    rotation.y += deltaX
    _viewMatrix = updateViewMatrix()
}
```

it now runs smoothly. This is crazy since I see no obvious reason. I do not try to change a constant and even the linter advises me to change the `var` to `let` in `deltaX` definition.

I feel like this is a Swift issue but this is worrying for a 5th version of a language used by many.

I would update my answer if I find a solution or at least a valid explanation.

Live long and prosper lads!